# Combine Django filters

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to check if `chron_id` is present and get rows without duplicates.
If `chron_id` is null then get all rows.

```
toponymies_one = Toponymy.objects.filter(chron_id__isnull=False).distinct('chron_id')
toponymies_two = Toponymy.objects.filter(chron_id__isnull=True)
```

Should I merge these two query sets? Is there a better way to do it?

```
| id | somevalue | somevalue | chron_id |
|----|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 1  | foo       | foo       |          | # I want this row
| 2  | bar       | foo       | 2        |
| 3  | foo       | bar       |          | # I want this row
| 4  | foo       | foo       |          | # I want this row
| 5  | bar       | foo       | 5        |
| 6  | foo       | bar       |          | # I want this row
| 7  | foo       | foo       |          | # I want this row
| 8  | bar       | foo       | 5        | # I want this row
| 9  | foo       | bar       | 2        | # I want this row
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

What about using OR statment in filter via `Q` vide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects